# Error with matrix not matching size of training set in R

Tags: r, regression

I am working a making a Ridge Regression model for a project. My `trainLed` data set has 2055 obs of 21 variables, with `Lifeexpectancy` being the one I am studying. When I use the code below my `train.mat` only has 1917 and I receive the error message when trying to run the ridge regression code.  what can I do to get the number of observations to match?

CODE:

```
train.mat = model.matrix(Lifeexpectancy~.,data=trainLed)


test.mat = model.matrix(Lifeexpectancy~.,data=testLed)

grid = 10^seq(4,-2,length = 120)

fit.ridge = glmnet(train.mat,trainLed$Lifeexpectancy,alpha=0,lambda=grid,thresh=1e-12)
```

**ERROR WHEN RUNNING LINE 4**
*Error in glmnet(train.mat, trainLed$Lifeexpectancy, alpha = 1, lambda = grid,  :
number of observations in y (2055) not equal to the number of rows of x (1917)*

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because some of your independent variables are NA, and `model.matrix()` will skip these rows.

For example, we make a similar dataset with 100 NAs coming from different columns, I get the same error:

```
trainLed = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2055*11),ncol=11))
colnames(trainLed) = c(paste0("var",1:10),"Lifeexpectancy")
trainLed$var1[1:50] = NA
trainLed$var2[51:100] = NA

train.mat = model.matrix(Lifeexpectancy~.,data=trainLed)
fit.ridge = glmnet(train.mat,trainLed$Lifeexpectancy,alpha=0)

Error in glmnet(train.mat, trainLed$Lifeexpectancy, alpha = 0) : 
  number of observations in y (2055) not equal to the number of rows of x (1955)
```

Subset your data to have complete observations:

```
trainLed = trainLed[complete.cases(trainLed),]
train.mat = model.matrix(Lifeexpectancy~.,data=trainLed)
fit.ridge = glmnet(train.mat,trainLed$Lifeexpectancy,alpha=0)
```